# How to set progrss bar in javaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

This is my code for progress bar.But the problem is the progress and indicator not working when some process is in working.When my code is running the progress bar initiated by -1.0f and and initiated at last by 1.0f.I was write the loop so the progress bar updated.But this is not working....I cant get it the problem...
The following code is for thread every time the progress bar set by new value but on GUI the progress bar not rendered.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(currentNuggetCount);
                                progressIndicator.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress());
                                System.out.println(" > thread running > ");
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaFX it's better to use `Service` and `Task` for thread. And that work really well with progress bar.

For example you have a ProgressBar on your view, you can bind like this : `progressBar.progressProperty().bind(yourservice.progressProperty);`

And on your service something like that :

```
Service s = new Service() {
    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        return new Task() {
            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {
               for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
               {
                   updateProgress(i, 10);
               }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Your progression will be automatically updated. You can also bind your the visibleProperty of your bar to the runningProperty of the service, and the bar will be displayed only when the service is running

Comment: In which package Service is present? Like java.security,javafx.consurrent,javax.xml,com.sun,

Comment: javafx.concurrent.Service; Service can take a return type. But i'm sur if you read http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm you'll understand better

Comment: I was inport javafx.concurrent package...and sry but not working I replace Platform.runlater with service but In my code there is no entry in this method.....

Comment: You need to call your service by  yourService.restart()

Comment: But I have written my whole code in controller den? I have not used 
MVC nodel.

Comment: I dont get it You need to call your service by yourService.restart()?

Comment: yes each time you want to use your service you call yourService.restart() and your service will start. you have different method like cancel, reset ... to manage your service

Comment: it is also worth adding a listener to determine when the task is not running:
`s.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>(){
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> ov,
                    Worker.State oldval, Worker.State newval)
                    {
                        if (newval != Worker.State.RUNNING)
                        {
                            //' react on UI
                        }
                    }
           });`